# PDO Prepared Statement not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, prepared-statement

I've been trying to get a proof-of-concept together all day using mysqli's prepared statements but have since decided to for PDO due to it's ability to bind values -- I believe i need them due to the dynamic nature of my queries.

The form behind the scenes is like so: http://pasteboard.co/k6H0cVq.png - You can also get an idea of the concept here. My query is returning no results or errors, just a warning  `Array to string conversion` - which occurs when binding the values.

I am also worried that my binding of the value aren't working, i can't put them in the foreach loop as it can't be situated before the `$stmt` variable is called, otherwise even more errors are thrown out.

I've been reading docs and watching tutorials but i can't find anything which shows how to implement a model where the queries are dynamic.

I hope i'm clear enough, it's been a frustrating endeavour trying to get my head around PDO and prepared statements in general.

Any help is **much** appreciated. 
Thanks!

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['platform'], $_POST['bandwidth'], $_POST['price'])){

    $platform = $_POST['platform'];
    $bandwidth = $_POST['bandwidth'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM 'hosts' WHERE";

    foreach($platform as $platform) {
        $query .= " 'platform' LIKE %:platform% OR";
    }   
    $query = substr($query, 0, -2); 

    foreach($bandwidth as $bandwidth) {
        $query .= " AND 'bandwidth' BETWEEN :bandwidth OR";
    }   
    $query = substr($query, 0, -2); 

    foreach($price as $price) {
        $query .= " AND 'price' BETWEEN :price OR";
    }   
    $query = substr($query, 0, -2); 

    $conn =  new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=test', 'root', '');
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    if ($_POST['platform']){
        $stmt->bindValue(':platform', $_POST['platform']);  
    }

    if ($_POST['bandwidth']){
        $stmt->bindValue(':bandwidth', $_POST['bandwidth']);    
    }   

    if ($_POST['price']){
        $stmt->bindValue(':price', $_POST['price']);    
    }   

    $stmt->execute();

    foreach($stmt as $row) {
        print_r($row); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use the same named placeholder multiple times.  You can't bind arrays to placeholders.  If you have placeholders, they need to be bound - so don't bind conditionally.  There's no such operator as `BETWEEN ... OR ...`.  You ought to use a variable name for the value assignment in the `foreach()` statement that is different to the name of the array over which it is iterating.  You ought to activate a PDO error mode that will cause error information to be displayed, or else explicitly test for error conditions.  That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks. When you talk about the placeholders is it regarding the likes of this: 'bandwidth' BETWEEN :bandwidth **OR** foreach ($price as $price)

Comment: You're using the wrong type of quotes around the column names in the query, they should be backticks, not single quotes.

Comment: Placeholders are the words after `:`.

Comment: You also need to be concerned with the precedence of `AND` and `OR`, you probably need parentheses around all your `OR` groups.

Comment: You can't write `LIKE %:platform%`, as the argument to `LIKE` must be a string. It should be `LIKE CONCAT('%', :platform, '%')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rewrite of your code. I use arrays to build up the nested `AND` and `OR` conditions, using `implode` to combine them, rather than sequences of string concatenation. I give each placeholder a different name, using the array index. I changed all your `BETWEEN` clauses to `=` because `BETWEEN` requires two parameters, a beginning and end of the range.

```
if (isset($_POST['platform'], $_POST['bandwidth'], $_POST['price'])){

    $platform = $_POST['platform'];
    $bandwidth = $_POST['bandwidth'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM hosts";

    $ands = array();
    $bind_array = array();

    $ors = array();
    foreach($platform as $i => $platform) {
        $ors[] = "platform LIKE CONCAT('%', :platform{$i}, '%')";
        $bind_array[":platform{$i}"] = $platform;
    }   
    if ($ors) {
        $ands[] = "(" . implode(" OR ", $ors) . ")";
    }

    $ors = array();
    foreach($bandwidth as $i => $bandwidth) {
        $ors[] = "bandwidth = :bandwidth{$i}";
        $bind_array[":bandwidth{$i}"] = $bandwidth;
    }   
    if ($ors) {
        $ands[] = "(" . implode(" OR ", $ors) . ")";
    }

    $ors = array();
    foreach($price as $i => $price) {
        $ors[] = "price = :price{$i}";
        $bind_array[":price{$i}"] = $price;
    }

    if ($ors) {
        $ands[] = "(" . implode(" OR ", $ors) . ")";
    }
    if ($ands) {
        $query .= " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $ands);
    }

    $conn =  new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=test', 'root', '');
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute($bind_array);

    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        print_r($row); 
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

If you have two parameters `price1[]` and `price2[]` for a range, change the `price` loop to:

```
    foreach($price1 as $i => $price) {
        $ors[] = "price BETWEEN :pricelow{$i} AND :pricehigh{$i}";
        $bind_array[":pricelow{$i}"] = $price;
        $bind_array[":pricehigh{$i}"] = $price2[$i];
    }
```

Comment: I owe you **BIG** time, thanks friend! I will try this out in the morning (I'm from the UK).

Comment: Small issue - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS) on line 81. But, line 81 -- in notepad doesn't event contain an 'as'. Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: I had to try it, i couldn't wait. haha.

Comment: Good question! It's:                                               while($stmt as $row) {

Comment: That should be `foreach`. I started changing it to a `while`, then undid it incompletely.

Comment: It seems to be working! Thanks so much, I'll study the code and try to learn how everything's working.

Comment: Beware that if the arrays are keyed with strings (e.g. form elements were named `platform[foo]` etc) then they might contain characters invalid in SQL identifiers (one would have to quote the identifiers and escaping any quotes contained therein).  Or else make `$i` a counter that increments on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: He hasn't shown his HTML, I assumed the arrays were created from form elements with names like `platform[]`, which PHP automatically turns into numeric arrays.

Comment: Agreed, that is most likely.  Just thought it was worth mentioning in case (or for future readers).

Comment: Form elements with names like platform[] -- That's correct.

Comment: @Barmar -- How would i go about using a between statement for price if i had two parameters named $price1 and $price2?

Comment: Thanks again man, I tried the same thing before but i missed the `$price2[$i]`. I really need to brush up on my PHP. Have you any idea why that foreach argument is causing this error, i mean it still works :L `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` -- It's referring to the foreach you supplied in your updated code. Could it be because the input is not an array -- as it's just a textbox?

Comment: Update: I appended `[]` to the name of each input to format it as an array -- Which removed the warning. Is that good form? Or would it be less efficient?

Comment: My answer assumed multiple price ranges, just like there were multiple platforms and bandwidths.  If you just have one price range, you don't need to add `[]` to the input names, and you don't need `foreach` -- just add a single `price between :price1 and :price2` entry to `$ands` array.

Answer (score -2):

I'm afraid you can't iterate over the statement as you're trying to do. Instead use the [fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) method to access the results of the query:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch([fetch mode, e.g., PDO::FETCH_ASSOC])) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Regarding the "Array to string conversion" error you get, I suspect that one or more of the POST variables is in fact an array. To test this hypothesis, try print_r($_POST).

Comment: Also, i know they're arrays, if you take a look at the image in link the select boxed are allow multiple options thus returning an array.

Comment: I think you meant to type: while ($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ))  -  For me, it doesn't returning errors. But still hasn't fixed the bigger issue at hand. :-(

Comment: -1 This answer is so far off the mark.  `PDOStatement` implements [`Traversable`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php), so one absolutely can iterate over it with `foreach()` as the OP had originally done.  Furthermore, this answer completely fails to identify any of the multitude of other (serious) problems with the OP's code.

Comment: @eggyal I did not know that PDOStatement implements Traversable and appreciate the information. That being said, your comment is rude and, therefore, out of place.